# How do you use clang-analyzer with node-gyp?

Tags: node.js, c++, clang

I am trying to use https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org but my application is a C++ node addon. It utilizes node-gyp and a binding.gyp file to inform the compiler.

How might one utilize a static analyzer like clang-analyzer to accomplish this? Currently, it's usage documentation mentions using it to build the project you have in mind.

Normally, I'd run `npm run build:dev` which runs `node-gyp -j 8 --debug configure build`

Environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04